# How to pass data to database using WYSIWYG HTML Javascript Editor with Django.

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-forms, wysiwyg

After a lot of trial and error, I'm stuck.  I am trying to create my own WYSIWYG editor with Django.  I have created the WYSIWYG editor, I just can't seem to figure out how to incorporate my editor/HTML/Django form altogether.  Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base1.html" %}
<title>{% block title %} Create Information {% endblock %}</title>
{% block body_block %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete=off>

  <style>
   div#textEditor{ margin: 0 auto; width: 750px; height: 300px; }
   div#theRibbon{ border-bottom: none; padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(40,110,89); color: white; border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px; }
   div#richTextArea{ border: 2px solid rgb(40,110,89); height: 100%; width: 746px; background-color: white; }
   iframe#theWYSIWYG{ height: 100%; width: 100%; }
   div#theRibbon > button { color: white; border: none; outline: none; background-color: transparent; cursor: pointer; }
   div#theRibbon > button:hover{ background-color: rgb(20,90,70); transition: all 0.3s linear 0s; }
   input[type="color"]{ border: none; outline: none; background-color: transparent; }
   </style>

   <script> window.addEventListener("load",function(){ var editor = theWYSIWYG.document; editor.designMode = "on"; boldButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("Bold", false, null); },false);
   italicButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("Italic", false, null); },false);
   supButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("Superscript", false, null); },false);
   subButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("Subscript", false, null); },false);
   strikeButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("Strikethrough", false, null); },false);
   orderedListButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("InsertOrderedList", false, "newOL" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)); },false);
   unorderedListButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ editor.execCommand("InsertUnorderedList", false, "newOL" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)); },false);
   fontColorButton.addEventListener("change", function(event){ editor.execCommand("ForeColor", false, event.target.value); },false);
   highlightButton.addEventListener("change", function(event){ editor.execCommand("BackColor", false, event.target.value); },false);
   fontChanger.addEventListener("change", function(event){ editor.execCommand("FontName", false, event.target.value); },false);
   fontSizeChanger.addEventListener("change",function(event){ editor.execCommand("FontSize",false,event.target.value); },false);
   linkButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ var url = prompt("Enter a URL", "http://"); editor.execCommand("CreateLink", false, url); }, false);
   unLinkButton.addEventListener("click",function(){ editor.execCommand("UnLink",false,null); },false);
   undoButton.addEventListener("click",function(){ editor.execCommand("undo",false,null); },false);
   redoButton.addEventListener("click",function(){ editor.execCommand("redo",false,null); },false);
   submitButton.addEventListener("click",function(){ richText.value = theWYSIWYG.document.body.innerHTML; theForm.submit(); },false); },false);
 </script>

{% csrf_token %}

<div class="box3">

  <h2 class="title">Create New Information</h2>

    <label class="label6">New Information</label>

    <div id="textEditor">
      <div id="theRibbon">
        <button id="boldButton" title="Bold"><b>B</b></button>
        <button id="italicButton" title="Italic"><em>I</em></button>
        <button id="supButton" title="Superscript">X<sup>2</sup></button>
        <button id="subButton" title="Subscript">X<sub>2</sub></button>
        <button id="strikeButton" title="Strikethrough"><s>abc</s></button>
        <button id="orderedListButton" title="Numbered list">(i)</button>
        <button id="unorderedListButton" title="Bulleted list"">&bull;</button>
         <input type="color" id="fontColorButton" title="Change Font Color">
         <input type="color" id="highlightButton" title="Highlight Text">
         <select id="fontChanger">
           <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
           <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
           <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
           <option value="monospace">Monospace</option>
           <option value="cursive">Cursive</option>
           <option value="sans-serif">Sans-Serif</option>
           <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
         </select>
         <select id="fontSizeChanger">
           <script> for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){ document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>"); }
           </script>
         </select>
         <script> var fonts = document.querySelectorAll("select#fontChanger > option"); for(var i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++){ fonts[i].style.fontFamily = fonts[i].value; }
         </script>         

         <button id="linkButton" title="Create Link">Link</button>
         <button id="unLinkButton" title="Remove Link">Unlink</button>
         <button id="undoButton" title="Undo the previous action">&larr;</button>
         <button id="redoButton" title="Redo">&rarr;</button>
       </div>

       <div id="richTextArea">
           <iframe id="theWYSIWYG" name="theWYSIWYG" frameborder="0">
           <textarea name="newinformation">{{ form.newinformation }}</textarea>
         </iframe>

        </div>
      </div>
```

The form renders correctly, but ultimately I keep getting the following error 
"null value in column "newinformation" violates not-null constraint when I submit the form.  My model is defined correctly.  Essentially the data that I am putting in the WYSIWYG is not being passed on to the database.  I am using individual fields in my form, and I can't figure out how to essentially merge the WYSIWYG editor and my {{ form.newinformation }} field.  I incorporated the form.newinformation in my code sample above to show what I've tried but that does not work.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

your HTML is wrong.

your form does not closed and you put your input into an iFrame.

so when you POST your form content of iFrame does not post to server.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've been at this too long today.  I can close the form with no problem.  Where should I put the input?  I'm new to Javascript.  In the HTML form section?  Or in the Javascript?

Comment: you must add it into Form HTML and not into a IFrame .